# How to only obtain information from DHCP server without applying it on Linux

Tags: linux, networking, dhcp

If I do `dhclient eth1`, it obtains the information (IP address, router, DNS, etc.) and applies it to routing table, `/etc/resolv.conf` and so on.

How to only get and print the information from DHCP server without touching the network configuration?

Currently I use `dhcdrop -t`, but it is not the right tool for the job.

Comment: Should the information to be obtained be related to the interface eth1 as in your sample?

Comment: Yes.

Comment: One more question. The already cached information is not enough?

Comment: Already cached information on freshly set up or not DHCP-maanged interface? Actually the one use case is to set IP and _some_ routes based on DHCP reply, but not DNS.

Comment: You did not mention in the question that this is a freshly setup machine as well as that the interface is not dhcp managed.

Comment: Going to be requested on connection (hacky scheme). Proper scheme whould be DHCP client that keeps running and dumps replies from DHCP server where I can interpret and execute (or not execute) orders from it in my script. It can also be useful when you want to connect to multiple DHCP-managed networks. One of DHCP servers tell you "10.4.5.6 is defalt router", but you interpret it as "10.4.5.6 is router for 10.4.0.0/16" and so on.

Comment: @Serge, "You did not mention in the question" -> The solution should just send and receive the appropriate packets and not mess with routes/DNS/addresses/whatever. Almost like "query DHCP server from non-root" (if raw network were allowed for users).

Comment: Yes, I got you.